# Viewheight on Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup window, that is a div. It shouldn't go out of the screen, so I added an other div that is scrollable to facilitate the content if it's longer than the screen height. I can set the inner divs max-height in javascript like this (because I have content before it, so I  don't know where it starts.):

```
var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
container.style.maxHeight = "calc(100vh - " + rect.top + "px - 15vh)";
```

This approach works on computers, but on smartphones in Chrome, the viewheight is more than what the user actually sees, because the url bar takes up space, so when that bar is shown, the end of the div is out of the screen. So how can I make the div end "15vh" from the actual bottom of the screen.

My code:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
container.style.maxHeight = "calc(100vh - " + rect.top + "px - 15vh)";
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black; 
}
#popup_content {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
#container {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup_content">
  <p>some content</p>
  <div id="container">
    A lot of text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus, est vel congue eleifend, ante tortor ultricies leo, eu consectetur magna odio ac nibh. Nulla laoreet odio dui, ac aliquet purus porttitor et. Aliquam blandit vestibulum mauris, vel eleifend diam ultrices in. Vivamus eget eleifend dui. Cras aliquet libero et lorem venenatis ultricies. Vestibulum pulvinar erat eget velit porta, a gravida nunc scelerisque. Aliquam ut varius nibh. Aenean volutpat imperdiet nibh quis vestibulum. Donec eget magna varius, tempus augue ac, auctor ipsum. Vivamus quis egestas mauris. Vivamus dapibus risus hendrerit viverra ullamcorper. Pellentesque sodales elementum leo, sit amet ultricies elit rhoncus eu. Phasellus consectetur sit amet sem at mattis. Aliquam finibus risus ut ante pharetra, ut condimentum ligula convallis. Maecenas hendrerit, ligula at finibus pellentesque, justo ante varius metus, a luctus libero dui ut risus. Pellentesque dictum, risus ut fermentum tincidunt, purus massa dictum lectus, id aliquam neque risus at augue. Phasellus laoreet fermentum elementum. Donec sit amet aliquam neque. In consequat nec augue aliquam congue. Suspendisse purus neque, luctus vel placerat sed, pellentesque eget neque. Morbi tincidunt iaculis neque in imperdiet. Donec id tortor nunc. In lacinia rhoncus lectus, vitae feugiat felis egestas at.
  </div>
</div>
```